# Access element of the struct in array of structs

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, struct, swift5

Hi I have a task to implement the Fleet protocol which has two functions:

addNewCar - adds a new car object to the Fleet.
- Parameter car: car to add to the Fleet
- Returns: false if the car with same id already exists in the Fleet, true – otherwise.

deleteCar - Deletes the car with the specified id from the Fleet.
- Returns: true if the car with same id existed in the Fleet, false – otherwise.

**listCarsByModel** - returns 10 car models containing the specified string.
If there are several cars with the same model, brand's name is added to car's model in the format "brand - car",
otherwise returns simply "car".

**listCarsByBrand** - returns 10 car models whose brand contains the specified string,
result is ordered by brand.

```
struct Car {
    let id: String; // unique identifier
    let model: String;
    let brand: String;
}

protocol Fleet {
    func addNewCar(car: Car) -> Bool

    func deleteCar(id: String) -> Bool

    func listCarsByModel(searchString: String) -> Set<String>

    func listCarsByBrand(searchString: String) -> [String]

}


class FleetImpl: Fleet {
    var cars: [Car] = []

    func addNewCar(car: Car) -> Bool {
        if let i = cars.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == car.id }) {
            print(i)
            return false
        } else {
            cars.append(car)
            print(car)
            return true
        }
    }

    func deleteCar(id: String) -> Bool {

        return true
    }

    func listCarsByModel(searchString: String) -> Set<String> {

    }

    func listCarsByBrand(searchString: String) -> [String] {

    }
}
```

I've used method firstIndex(where:). But the function adds new car to the array with existing id. (i.e. two or more cars with the same id)

How can I access that 'id' property of Car struct in order to manipulate that data?
Please help me out

This is the test code:

```
func test(fleet: Fleet) {
    assert(!fleet.deleteCar(id: "1"))
    assert(fleet.addNewCar(car: Car(id: "1", model: "1", brand: "Lex")))
    assert(!fleet.addNewCar(car: Car(id: "1", model: "any name because we check id only", brand: "any brand")))
    assert(fleet.deleteCar(id: "1"))
    assert(fleet.addNewCar(car: Car(id: "3", model: "Some Car3", brand: "Some Brand2")))
    assert(fleet.addNewCar(car: Car(id: "4", model: "Some Car1", brand: "Some Brand3")))

    var byModels: Set<String> = fleet.listCarsByModels(searchString: "Car")
    assert(byModels.count == 10)

byModels = fleet.listCarsByModels(searchString: "Some Car")
    assert(byModels.count == 4)
    assert(byModels.contains("Some Brand3 - Some Car1"))
    assert(byModels.contains("Some Car2"))
    assert(byModels.contains("Some Car3"))
    assert(!byModels.contains("Some Car1"))
    assert(byModels.contains("Some Brand1 - Some Car1"))

var byBrand: [String] = fleet.listCarsByBrand(searchString: "Brand")
    assert(byBrand.count == 10)

byBrand = fleet.listCarsByBrand(searchString: "Some Brand")
    assert(byBrand.count == 4)
    assert(byBrand[0] == "Some Car1")
    assert(byBrand[1] == "Some Car2" || byBrand[1] == "Some Car3")
    assert(byBrand[2] == "Some Car2" || byBrand[2] == "Some Car3")
    assert(byBrand[3] == "Some Car1")
}

test(fleet: FleetImpl())
```

Comment: "but somethings seems wrong." ***what*** seems wrong exactly?

Comment: Seems like you have a ```}``` mistake. There is one ```}``` is missing for protocol.

Comment: @Sweeper sorry, I've edited the question. The array shouldn't have two or more cars with the same id

Comment: @RajaKishan my bad, fixed it

Comment: Unrelated but this is Swift: No trailing semicolons! If`id` is really an *unique identifier* the add method is supposed to work. And if the array contains multiple items with the same id then your design is wrong.

Comment: can you please add example/test how you can add a new car?

Comment: @RajaKishan sure sir, please have a look. I've added it to the question

Comment: @vadian thank you for your answer sir. This is the exercise question, not the real project. So maybe the author didn't need the proper design

Comment: Everything is fine you got crash for your first test cause the assert is failed. You have are returning static true value on delete function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe a set instead of an array would work better in this case as we're dealing with `unique` elements. Also note that rather than using `firstIndex(where)` I'm using `first(where)` which will return the car rather than index.

```
import UIKit

struct Car: Hashable {
    let id: String
    let model: String
    let brand: String
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
}

protocol Fleet {
    func addNewCar(car: Car) -> Bool
    func deleteCar(id: String) -> Bool
    func listCarsByModel(searchString: String) -> [String]
    func listCarsByBrand(searchString: String) -> [String]
}

class FleetImpl: Fleet {
    var cars = Set<Car>()

    func addNewCar(car: Car) -> Bool {
        guard !cars.contains(where: { $0.id == car.id }) else { return false }
        
        cars.insert(car)
        return true
    }

    func deleteCar(id: String) -> Bool {
        guard let car = cars.first(where: { $0.id == id }) else { return false }
        
        cars.remove(car)
        return true
    }
    
    func listCarsByModel(searchString: String) -> [String] {
        let searchedCars = cars.filter { $0.model.lowercased().contains(searchString.lowercased()) }.sorted { $0.brand < $1.brand }
        var formattedModels = [String]()
        searchedCars.forEach { car in
            if let car = searchedCars.first(where: { $0.model == car.model && $0.id != car.id }) {
                let carName = [car.model, car.brand].joined(separator: " - ")
                formattedModels.append(carName)
            } else {
                formattedModels.append(car.model)
            }
        }
        return Array(formattedModels.prefix(10))
    }
    
    func listCarsByBrand(searchString: String) -> [String] {
        let searchedBrands = cars.filter { $0.brand.lowercased().contains(searchString.lowercased()) }.sorted { $0.brand < $1.brand }.map { $0.model }
        return Array(searchedBrands.prefix(10))
    }
    
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. It work just fine. There are couple more functions to be added. Do you mind helping with that too

Comment: @Russ What other functions need to be added? Could you update the question with them.

Comment: I've edited the question by adding the functions (listCarsByModel & listCarsByBrand). Please have a look. Thank you very much for your help mate, appreciate it a lot

Comment: @Russ I've updated my answer not the most efficient solution but hopefully this is what you're after :)

Comment: Thank you so much  God bless you